# Как в экселе добавить в формулу вычисляемую ячейку?

Tags: excel

В строке формул нужно подсунуть ячейку, номер которой получен какими-то вычислениями, например, С(2*3+7), то есть, С13. Можно ли как-то это сделать?

Вообще, мне нужно получить сумму значений в столбце С от вычисленной таким образом ячейки и до конца, то есть, =СУММ(С(2*3+7):C100)

Comment: откуда берется эта формула и значения в ней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```
=СУММ(ДВССЫЛ("C" & 2*3+7):C100)

или

=СУММ(ДВССЫЛ("C" &  2*3+7):ДВССЫЛ("C100"))

или

=СУММ(СМЕЩ(C1;2*3+7-1;0):C100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно функции листа пересчитываются только когда меняются входные данные. Но есть несколько функций, которые реагируют на любое изменение на листе, их еще называют летучими. Среди них `СМЕЩ` и `ДВССЫЛ`. Применение таких функций рекомендуется, когда нет замены, которая может выполнить задачу. `ДВССЫЛ` - эту вообще на самый крайний случай: летучая, не работает с другими книгами, тормознутая (ей еще тест в ссылку преобразовывать).

```
=СУММ(ИНДЕКС(C:C;2*3+7):C100)
```

`ИНДЕКС`, как и большинство функций, пересчитывается только при изменении входных данных. Но если диапазон в теле функции с вычислениями, то пересчет происходит, но только при открытиии книги (это можно проверить, если книгу открыть и закрыть без каких-либо изменений - появится сообщение о необходимости сохранении данных). При уже открытой книге функция реагирует только на изменение входных данных.